# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating an ecommerce with react. I'm trying to create a function who shows the product details. But I do not know how to approach this problem. After to be linked to the url of the details in the browser, the url is the right one, but the details are not renderer and get the following message:

ProductDetails.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Down here you can read the ProductDetails.js and App.js files.
This is my react-router-dom version v6.4.1

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';
import Home from './components/layout/Home'
import './App.css';
import ProductDetails from './components/product/ProductDetails';

    function App() {
      return( 
        <>
        <Header/>
        <Footer/>
        <Routes>
         
        <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductDetails/>} />
    
        <Route/>
      </Routes>
      </>
        )
    }
    
    export default App;



import React, {useEffect, Fragment} from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getProductDetails, clearErrors } from '../../actions/productActions';
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert';
import Loader from '../layout/Loader';
import MetaData from '../layout/MetaData';


const ProductDetails = ({match}) => {
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
     const alert = useAlert();
     const {loading, error, product} = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)

 useEffect(()=>{
dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id))
if(error){
    alert.error(error);
    dispatch(clearErrors());
}

 },[dispatch, alert, error, match.params.id])

  return (
    <Fragment>
    {loading ? <Loader/> : (
        <Fragment>
            
        <div className="row f-flex justify-content-around">
            <div className="col-12 col-lg-5 img-fluid" id="product_image">
                <img src="https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1223a935-2a61-480a-95a1-21904ff8986c_1.17fa3d7870e3d9b1248da7b1144787f5.jpeg?odnWidth=undefined&odnHeight=undefined&odnBg=ffffff" alt="sdf" height="500" width="500"/>
            </div>

            <div className="col-12 col-lg-5 mt-5">
                <h3>"{product.name}</h3>
                <p id="product_id">Product # sklfjdk35fsdf5090</p>

                <hr/>

                <div className="rating-outer">
                    <div className="rating-inner"></div>
                </div>
                <span id="no_of_reviews">(5 Reviews)</span>

                <hr/>

                <p id="product_price">$108.00</p>
                <div className="stockCounter d-inline">
                    <span className="btn btn-danger minus">-</span>

                    <input type="number" className="form-control count d-inline" value="1" readOnly />

                    <span className="btn btn-primary plus">+</span>
                </div>
                 <button type="button" id="cart_btn" className="btn btn-primary d-inline ml-4">Add to Cart</button>

                <hr/>

                <p>Status: <span id="stock_status">In Stock</span></p>

                <hr/>

                <h4 className="mt-2">Description:</h4>
                <p>Binge on movies and TV episodes, news, sports, music and more! We insisted on 720p High Definition for this 32" LED TV, bringing out more lifelike color, texture and detail. We also partnered with Roku to bring you the best possible content with thousands of channels to choose from, conveniently presented through your own custom home screen.</p>
                <hr/>
                <p id="product_seller mb-3">Sold by: <strong>Amazon</strong></p>
                
                <button id="review_btn" type="button" className="btn btn-primary mt-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ratingModal">
                            Submit Your Review
                </button>
                
                <div className="row mt-2 mb-5">
                    <div className="rating w-50">

                        <div className="modal fade" id="ratingModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ratingModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div className="modal-content">
                                    <div className="modal-header">
                                        <h5 className="modal-title" id="ratingModalLabel">Submit Review</h5>
                                        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="modal-body">

                                        <ul className="stars" >
                                            <li className="star"><i className="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                                            <li className="star"><i className="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                                            <li className="star"><i className="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                                            <li className="star"><i className="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                                            <li className="star"><i className="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                                        </ul>

                                        <textarea name="review" id="review" className="form-control mt-3">

                                        </textarea>

                                        <button className="btn my-3 float-right review-btn px-4 text-white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                        
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
        </Fragment>
    )}
    </Fragment>
    
  )
}

export default ProductDetails
```

Comment: You're not passing the params props anywhere to the component. I would suggest to use the hook useParams from react-router-dom to read the id from the route: https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#useparams

Comment: Thanks for your time. I already fixed using useParams.

Answer (score 0):

1-) Add the following line of code at the beginning of your class:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
```

2-) Then add this function above your class (copy it exactly):

```
 export function withRouter(Children){
 return(props)=>{

    const match  = {params: useParams()};
    return <Children {...props}  match = {match}/>
  }
 }
```

3-) Next, change your class definition to this:

```
class EditExercises extends Component{
```

4-) Add the following line of code at the end of your class:

```
export default withRouter(EditExercises);
```